# Comuter freezing on full RAM/possible cache problem

Tags: linux, arch-linux, memory, ram, freeze

After installing Arch Linux on my Notebook I experience a weird problem: Opening firefox or any other browser (or any application with high RAM usage) RAM (12 GB) is filling up pretty quickly, even after closing everything, to the point of a complete system freeze.

I have Arch Linux with basically the same configuration installed on an other system with 4GB of RAM and everything works fine.

Using

```
free -mh
```

shortly before everything freezes and after closing all applications gives me the following output

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           11Gi        402Mi       1.1Gi       9.5Gi       9.9Gi       1.2Gi
Swap:          4.0Gi       787Mi       3.2Gi
```

So as far as I understand Linux should free the memory in the cache when it is needed but this never happens. Further i can't clean the cache manually with

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

I scoured the internet for a possible solution but nothing seems to work. I tried messing with swappines and min_free_kbytes as discussed in some other posts but this didn't work for me.

What is odd to me is the column shared because it seems to me very high. On my other PC the memory size in shared column is maybe half of cache/buff, most of the time even lower.

I guess something is filling up my memory but I cant figure out what. According to some other posts I checked `df -h` which gives me following output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev             5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
run             5.8G  976K  5.8G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  36G   12G  23G    33% /
tmpfs           5.8G    0K  5.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.8G  4.0K  5.8G   1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p3  198G   2.4G  185G  2% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p1  510M   64M  447M  13% /boot
tmpfs           1.2G   20K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

I can't see anything odd about it (maybe that /dev/shm/ is not used?)

So how can I find out what application is using most of the RAM and how do I fix this?

Comment: There's no need to clean the cache, this is done by the kernel. To look at SHM, use `top -o SHR` to monitor

Comment: enable systemd-oomd or earlyoom.

Comment: _"shortly before everything freezes and after closing all applications"_ ... makes no sense. If you close the application, why would the host freeze? Also, what do you mean "freezes"? Do you have to reboot the machine when it happens?